# d3 v5 add dots to nested line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested, linechart

I need to add a dot on the value lines for each data point (ie. x = year, y= # events BY region). Each region has it's own line per the nest function. Please see fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/32yL4bd9/

The data is nested 2x and has a rollup defined:

```
  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.region;
    })
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    })
    .rollup(function(leaves) {
      return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
        return parseInt(d.count, 10);
      });
    })
    .entries(dataset)
```

I believe it is an issue with the nested data and the looping. I have tried to add the dot in this way:

```
        // Draw dots on line
        svg
          .selectAll(".dot")
          .data(nest)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "dot")
          .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
            return xScale(new Date(d.values.key));
            // d.values.forEach(function(value){
            //   return xScale( new Date(value.key))
            // })
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.values.value);
            // d.values.forEach(function(value){
            //   return yScale(Number(value.value))
            // })
          })
          .attr("r", 5);
```

Comment: I think you can just call the date data directly: https://jsfiddle.net/t85f62yz/

Comment: thanks! the dots do appear but there are not on the lines.

Comment: Ok, well, which level are you expecting to see?

Comment: thanks! at the level of the nested data.

Comment: Ok, well, you weren't sending it nested data so it never knew to do that. In this fiddle I mapped the nested values to a variable and iterated over that to draw each set of circles: https://jsfiddle.net/8cn92yha/